# Multiple independent Webpages in VS2010 Webform without using Frames, Iframes and Ajax

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html

Frames/ Framesets has been deprecated.

Iframes are not recomended for various reasons.

Ajax is not always an option since one of the providers may not support it.

So how does one converge & display multiple html content from two different sources in a Asp.Net 4.0 or higher page  as per modern HTML standard ?

Should i focus completely on ajax/partial page related development or continue using Iframe as  a stop gap measure hoping they dont deprecate it too in the near future ?

Comment: Ajax is not always an option since one of the providers may not support it - could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @WiktorZychla It all depends on the archetecture of your partner sites whether they supoort ajax and return a partial web content or a full html.

Answer (score 0):

well there was a time when even facebook was on iframe, now its all about partial responses. But iframes are not going anywhere soon ,we still get many of our client requirement specific to iframes and if it suits your need to achieve compatibility why are you confusing yourself with alternates.
besides that html5 has added some new spices to iframe so its clear that this thing is not going in bin.
so in the end , i would suggest:
1. Go for ajax/partial/jquery if you want your application to be both interactive & user friendly.
2. If compatibility is a big issue then go straight to iframes.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Alok. But i am worried about the scenario 5-7 years from now when a next upgrade will be due for my application. Will iframe be still there ? One big issue is puting headers, menu and navigation related stuff in a page and and other pages in a iframe which saves a lot of time and resources since each time a child page is loaded i dont have to reload the parent page content. I have a upgrade due now. if iframe will be there in the future i am going for webforms  otherwise i have to move on to MVC/Ajax which is altogether a different matter and requires considerable changes and is costly.

Comment: iframe will be their , no doubt about that. But a 5-7 years scenario you should better move to latest technology. Although turning whole application into something else is very costly and time demanding, so if you are not considering parameters such as SEO, Accesibility and content compatibility in browser(as iframe tends to break in some browser or behave strangely); you cant stick to it. Apart from that why are you using iframes when the master page is just their.

Comment: i use iframes because i have to show a lot of pdfs (reports) which i cant display using masterpages. On the top of that the report viwer controls by MS,SAP add a lot of weight hugging my bandwidth.

Comment: ok, then iframes are good and as i said above they are not going anywhere.